# Error uploading Google App Engine Application

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, yaml, app.yaml

I am using a normal command to upload my application in Google App Engine (Python 2.7, SDK 1.8.9):

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 update .
```

But after a refactoring in my project there is an error in a regular expression for app.yaml ([here is the code](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/app.yaml))

The error is:

```
02:00 AM Application: sandengine; version: dev
02:00 AM Host: appengine.google.com
02:00 AM Starting update of app: sandengine, version: dev
02:00 AM Getting current resource limits.
02:00 AM Scanning files on local disk.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 199, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 195, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4933, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4924, in main
result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2648, in Run
self.action(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4604, in __call__
return method()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3419, in Update
self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3466, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3357, in UpdateVersion
return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2143, in DoUpload
self._AddFilesThatAreSmallEnough(paths, openfunc)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2211, in _AddFilesThatAreSmallEnough
file_classification = FileClassification(self.config, path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 257, in __init__
self.__static_mime_type = self.__GetMimeTypeIfStaticFile(config, filename)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 287, in __GetMimeTypeIfStaticFile
if re.match(regex, filename):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\1'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a regular expression error, where in upload: you can't use \1 or \2

Here is the fix: https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/commit/7fbcba2cb217f8ccd8ced7bfe634b4aceaf616c6

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "dev" as the version number, try putting in an actual number :)

Answer (score 0):

dev is a reserved keyword. Change the version and instead of dev use a number or a lowercase string.

It Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy to figure out what file of your app.yaml is the problem by putting a print here.

/home/nburn42/Apps/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py

line 315

It is maybe a bit overkill but it will definitely get you unstuck.